# Joining two dataframes on matching values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe of transactions between people but its based of their ID number:

df =

```
First ID   Second ID   Total   Currency
854        938         50      GBP
321        438         30      EUR
756        850         50      USD
etc...
```

I also have a second df which contains the IDs and the actual names of the people they are linked to.

ID_df =

```
ID code   Name
321       John
850       David
etc...
```

I want to join the ID df onto the main dataframe so that i would have the names of the people. Ideally i would like it to look like:

df =

```
First ID   First name   Second ID   Second name   Total  Currency
854        Steve        938         Mike          60     Eur
etc...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

What's the issue with 2 back to back joins? (*you can make a function out of it in case it becomes 2+*)

```
df = df.merge(id_df,how='left',left_on='first_id',right_on='id_code')\
       .rename(columns={'name':'first_name'})

df = df.merge(id_df,how='left',left_on='second_id',right_on='id_code')\
       .rename(columns={'name':'second_name'})
```